# Travis CI Build error

Tags: travis-ci

I have via semantic-release generated a travis.yml file which looks like this:

```
sudo: false
language: node_js
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
notifications:
  email: false
node_js:
  - 'iojs'
before_install:
  - npm i -g npm@^2.0.0
before_script:
  - npm prune
  script:
  - npm run test:single
after_success:
  - npm run semantic-release
branches:
  except:
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

After doing a git push, I am getting following error from Travis:

```
ERROR: An error occured while trying to parse your .travis.yml file.
Please make sure that the file is valid YAML.
http://lint.travis-ci.org can check your .travis.yml.
The log message was: Build config file had a parse error: did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 13 column 3.
```

In the email from Travis I am also getting the following System message:

System message:
We are seeing build failures due to new sudo-enabled Precise and Trusty images. See more details [here](https://www.traviscistatus.com/incidents/11hp8bhkrkn7). Thank you for your enduring patience.

So is there a error in my travis.yml file or is it something else?

Thanks
Sohail

Comment: Did you paste it into [lint.travis-ci.org](http://lint.travis-ci.org)?

Answer (score 3):

Removed whitespace from:

```
  script:
  - npm run test:single
```

to:

```
script:
  - npm run test:single
```

Answer (score 1):

There is formatting error at line 13: `before_script` section.
Validate your yaml file.

There exist online-validators I list a few examples without any preference:

- http://www.yamllint.com/
- https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator

Comment: Got the same error with the validator. The actual error lays in the whitespace for the script attribute. When I deleted that whitespace, its working properly now :)

Comment: great to know it got fixed :)

Comment: Your link is deprecated.

Comment: yes, they closed the website :/ In case you find an alternate, please do update it here

Comment: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#lint

Comment: A link to online validator is what we are looking for, but that certainly is a good alternate

Comment: You can check your travis.yml file online for simple syntax errors http://www.yamllint.com/